# awk - how to replace semicolon in string in csv file?

Tags: bash, csv, awk

I need to manage smtp logfile handling in my company.

These logfiles need to be imported to MSSQL, so it is my job to provide this data.

I got strange undelivery message with a ";" in the string, I need to replace this with a comma.

So what I got:

```
Sender;Recipient;Operation;Answer;Error;Servername
bla@bla.com;rockit@sohard.com;RCPT TO;450;+4.2.0+<rockit@sohard.com>:+Recipient+address+rejected:+Policy+restrictions;+try+later;M0641
```

Mention the ";" in the Answer field after "restrictions", dunno why the mail server sends semicolons, maybe to annoy me :P

I tried following with awk after I did a lot of research:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"} {for (i=5;i<=NF;i++) gsub (";",",",$i)} 1' myfile.csv
```

This command actually works but it seems it does nothing with my file, the ";" in the error field remains. What I am missing here ?

Comment: Since semicolon is set as your delimiter, awk treats it unsurprisingly as the delimiter.  So your script won't be able to find freestanding semicolons to be replaced.  You need a different approach...

Comment: No, your command doesn't work. How could it? You're splitting each line into fields at each `';` then asking it to replace each `;` **within** each field by a `,` but there **are no `;`s within any fields** since you split the input at `;`s. How should a script know when a `;` is within rather than between fields?

Comment: I guessed so :) I'll try Johns solution later, looks quite good.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Replacing the fifth and later `;` with `,`

```
$ awk -F\; '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf "%s%s",$i,(i==NF?ORS:(i<=4?";":","))}' myfile.csv 
Sender;Recipient;Operation;Answer;Error,Servername
bla@bla.com;rockit@sohard.com;RCPT TO;450;+4.2.0+<rockit@sohard.com>:+Recipient+address+rejected:+Policy+restrictions,+try+later,M0641
```

How it works:

- `-F\;`

  This sets the field separator for input to `;`.
- `for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf "%s%s",$i,(i==NF?ORS:(i<=4?";":","))`

  This loops over every field and prints the field followed by (a) ORS if we are on the last field, or (b) `,` if were are on field 5 or later, or (c) `;` if we are on one of the first four fields.

## Replacing all `;` with `,`

Try:

```
$ awk -F\; '{$1=$1} 1' OFS=, myfile.csv
Sender,Recipient,Operation,Answer,Error,Servername
bla@bla.com,rockit@sohard.com,RCPT TO,450,+4.2.0+<rockit@sohard.com>:+Recipient+address+rejected:+Policy+restrictions,+try+later,M0641
```

How it works:

- `-F\;`

  This sets the field separator on input to a semicolon.
- `$1=$1`

  This causes awk to think the the line has been changed so that awk will update the output line to use the new field separator.
- `1`

  This tells awk to print the line.
- `OFS=,`

  This sets the field separator on output to a comma.

#### Alternative #1

```
$ awk '{gsub(/;/, ",")} 1' myfile.csv
Sender,Recipient,Operation,Answer,Error,Servername
bla@bla.com,rockit@sohard.com,RCPT TO,450,+4.2.0+<rockit@sohard.com>:+Recipient+address+rejected:+Policy+restrictions,+try+later,M0641
```

#### Alternative #2

```
$ sed 's/;/,/g'  myfile.csv
Sender,Recipient,Operation,Answer,Error,Servername
bla@bla.com,rockit@sohard.com,RCPT TO,450,+4.2.0+<rockit@sohard.com>:+Recipient+address+rejected:+Policy+restrictions,+try+later,M0641
```

Comment: I don't think this answers OP question.  He's asking to replace the semicolon after the fifth one, not intended to be a delimiter.

Comment: @karakfa Interesting.  I was following the OP's text, not the sample code.  The OP provides no desired output.  You may be right.  The OP will need to clarify.

Comment: @karakfa I just added a method to substitute only the fifth or later `;`.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is replacing the unquotes delimiters in your logical 4th field in a five field wide input.  Although this script is repetitious should be easier to understand

```
$ awk '{n=split($0,a,";"); 
        for(i=1; i<4; i++)   printf "%s;", a[i]; 
        for(i=4; i<n-1; i++) printf "%s,", a[i]; 
        printf "%s;%s\n", a[n-1], a[n]}' file
```

A better way to write the same based on @Ed Morton's comments

```
$ awk -F';' '{for(i=1; i<NF-1; i++) printf "%s"(i<4?FS:","), $i; 
              print $(NF-1) FS $NF}' file
```

For the input

```
1;2;3;4a;4b;4c;5
1;2;3;4;5
```

it generates

```
1;2;3;4a,4b,4c;5
1;2;3;4;5
```

Answer (score 0):

If the offending semi-colons only appear in your 5th field then you can do this using GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match():

```
$ awk 'match($0,/(([^;]+;){4})(.*)(;[^;]+$)/,a){gsub(/;/,",",a[3]); print a[1] a[3] a[4]}' file
bla@bla.com;rockit@sohard.com;RCPT TO;450;+4.2.0+<rockit@sohard.com>:+Recipient+address+rejected:+Policy+restrictions,+try+later;M0641
```

Answer (score 0):

If your fifth `;` should be removed, append $6 to $5 and advance accordingly. This could be done with `for` loop (there are examples in SO) but since the fault is so near the end, we'll just do this in a simpler way:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=";"} NR==1 {nf=NF} NF==(nf+1) {$5=$5 "," $6; $6=$7; NF=nf} 1' file
```

Explained:

```
BEGIN {FS=OFS=";"}   # set separator
NR==1 {nf=NF}        # get field count from the first record (6)
NF==(nf+1) {         # if record is one field longer:
    $5=$5 "," $6     # append $6 to $5, comma-separated
    $6=$7            # set $7 (NF) to $6 (nf)
    NF=nf            # reset NF
} 1                  # output
```

Testing: Running the program and sending the output to `cut -d\; -f 5` outputs:

```
Error
+4.2.0+<rockit@sohard.com>:+Recipient+address+rejected:+Policy+restrictions,+try+later
```